# Detect Vehicle direction and brake while moving in iOS

Tags: ios, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion, acceleration

I am working on a vehicle motion iOS app. Like user is inside the vehicle and trace the vehicle direction, braking, steering. I am very new to device sensors.

After doing some research, I am able to get `Accelerometer` (x,y and z) and `Gyroscope` (roll, pitch and yaw) data using `CoreMotion framework`. Also I have seen [Apple Motion Graphs sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MotionGraphs/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)
Can anyone help me how to detect the direction and brake using this data.

I have gone through below stack overflow solutions but still getting stuck. Please help me to go further.

- [Detecting if a user is moving in a car](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869659/detecting-if-a-user-is-moving-in-a-car)
- [Detecting Acceleration in a car (iPhone Accelerometer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733249/detecting-acceleration-in-a-car-iphone-accelerometer)

Anyone has any tutorial or algorithm or library to track the same? Or any way to go ahead.

Any help would be appreciated Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of 'direction', try searching for 'heading': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341223/how-can-i-get-the-heading-of-the-device-with-cmdevicemotion-in-ios-5